# Transmit a cookie to sites on the same domain in ajax requests

Tags: ajax, cookies, http-headers, cross-domain, samesite

My site `a.domain` exposes a page whose scripts perform AJAX queries (using fetch) to `b.domain`.

During the first visit to `a.domain`, a cookie is sent to the client with the following parameters :

```
"httpOnly" : "true"
"secure"   : "true"
"domain"   : ".domain"
"sameSite" : tried Strict, Lax and None
```

`b.domain` has the following response headers :

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"     : "a.domain"
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods"    : "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS".
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"    : "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Credentials"
```

And the headers of the fetch requests are :

```
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
"Accept"       : "application/json"
"Credentials"  : "include"
```

The cookie is well transmitted to `a.domain` or if I visit `b.domain` *directly*, but not in AJAX requests.

**EDIT : the problem is the same whatever the value of the samesite parameter.**

Is there a way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

Comment: Thanks but this site doesn't talk about ajax requests. The samesite attribute doesn't change anything in my case.

Comment: The samesite attribute is for any cross-site request including AJAX. In fact AJAX requests are the main reason for sametime cookies!

Comment: Ok, so I should have mentioned that the problem is the same whatever the value of the samesite parameter.

Comment: Are you using "samesite" or "SameSite"? Have you confirmed the cookie is definitely being set with that in DevTools?

Comment: Yes the cookie is set, and is transmitted to both sites on direct access. I use "sameSite" ("SameSite" and "samesite" don't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it.
The problem was related to a misunderstanding of the credentials parameter in the fetch requests. `credentials` is not a header but a parameter of the request.
Once the parameter is out of the headers (and written in lowercase) everything works normally.